# Gateway LT210 wrong ram size reported by BIOS after restart

Tags: memory, bios, gateway

Just upgraded a Gateway LT210 from 1GB to 2GB, BIOS 1.26

When it boots, 2GB are recognized by both Bios and Windows. This is consistent, I can do it any number of times.

However, if I reboot (without powering off), whether it be from BIOS F10 or via Windows Restart, it reboots showing 1 GB in both BIOS and Windows.

So, at least with my unit (a 2107h) it's very predictable: Start from power-off = 2GB; warm restart = 1GB, both in BIOS and Windows.

FYI, (1) a Windows Hibernate and restart boots with 2GB, and (2) a Windows Standby also resumes with 2GB. This is consistent with my previous observation: A Hibernate is also a power off, so when restarting it has 2 GB; and a Standby keeps power to the RAM which I presume keeps the size unchanged.

Anybody ran across this identical situation ?

BTW the RAM is Corsair ValueSelect VS2GSDS667D2G

Cheers

Comment: I've seen it before, but never been able to fix it.